# Non-central expansion of exponential

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion, power-series, exponential-function

It is well know that

$$
e^x = \sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{(x-0)^i}{i!}.
$$

I put a trivial $x-0$ there to emphasise that it is expanded on $0$. I wonder how to make a non-central series that does not expand based on zero? Something like

$$
e^x = \sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{(x-a)^i}{i!} ????
$$

that is a sum of polynomial of $x - a$ for some $a$, not $x$.

This is trivial, because by Taylor series, and by definition $d^n e^x/ dx^n = e^x$, we have $e^x = e^a + e^a (x - a) + \cdots$, so

$$
e^x = e^a\sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{(x-a)^i}{i!}.
$$

But the RHS has an $e^a$ really annoys me. Imagine that one cannot compute $e^x$, but this representation requires to compute $e^a$. So my final queston is how to make an $a$-based expansion of $e^x$ by purely polynomials and without computing something like $e^a$?

Comment: $\sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{(x-a)^i}{i!}= e^{x-a}=e^xe^{-a}$

Comment: The taylor series also contains the derivates of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ , in this case $e^a$. We cannot let $e^a$ vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expansion of $e^{x}$ around  $0$ you can write $x^{i}=(x-a+a)^{i}= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{i} \binom i k (x-a)^{k}a^{i-k}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: aha, yes, of course! why is this down-voted?

Comment: Why is the down vote?

Comment: Note: you can also write $e^a=\sum\frac{a^i}{i!}$ and then the Cauchy product of the two series also gives the same 2D series outcome.